# flutter swiper when only have 1 item

Tags: flutter

[image]

using flutter swipper package, how to remove side image (my marked red) if have 1 item only?

I already try change to `viewportFraction: 1` but it's change width to full width, I wan't change size width, only hide side image

this part of my code

```
                             Swiper(
                                autoplay: true,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                    int index) {
                                  return InkWell(
                                    child: Card(
                                        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(
                                            bottom: 30
                                        ),
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                .circular(20)
                                        ),
                                        child: (
                                            ClipRRect(
                                                child: (
                                                    CachedNetworkImage(
                                                      imageUrl: dataPromo[index].bannerPath,
                                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                itemCount: dataPromo.length,
                                viewportFraction: 0.8,
                                scale: 0.9,
                              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried change the viewportFraction to `viewportFraction: 1.0`?

Comment: yes, but It be full width, I don;t wan't change the width

Comment: You can change to 1.0 to be full width, and increase the inner margin of the widget. Or even decrease the scale if you dont mind lose some height.